# roots of a polynomial linked to mock theta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

The following polynomial (after harmless factors dropped) is found [in the paper](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/142.pdf) entitled *Mock theta functions and quantum modular forms* by Folsom-Ono-Rhoades (see Theorem 1.1)
$$Q_k(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\prod_{j=1}^nz(1+z^j)^2.$$
**Note.** $Q_k(z)$ has degree $k^2-1$.

**Convention.** Assume empty products to be $1$.

> **Question.** Let $k\geq2$ be an integer. Is it true that $Q_k(z)$ has distinct roots over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Realizing that my comment does not concern the question as it is - from the point of view of the cited paper it is not quite natural to consider the polynomial $Q_k(z)$; they consider what could be denoted by $zQ_\infty(z)$ -- the point is that they only need its values at $2k$th roots of unity, and there only the first $k$ summands are nonzero.  As for the series itself, $$zQ_\infty(z)=z+z^2+3 z^3+4 z^4+6 z^5+10 z^6+15 z^7+21 z^8+30 z^9+43 z^{10}+...,$$it is interesting to note that$$(1+zQ_\infty(z))\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)=1-x^2+x^3+x^6+x^7-x^9+x^{10}-x^{14}+x^{18}-x^{20}+...+2x^{45}+...$$

Comment: The sequence $1,1,1,3,4,6,10,15,21,...$, with the above generating function, is [A059618](http://oeis.org/A059618) on OEIS.

Comment: Made a question out of it, http://mathoverflow.net/q/262655/41291